# Is it possible to render elements conditionally in NativeScript-Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript-vue

I hope you can help me to solve my problem.
I am working on a Nativescript-Vue Application and I want to render this conditionally:

```
<Label if="isRendering" text="This is a text"></Label>
```

But this does not work.

I already tried it with `<v-template if="..."></v-template>` but this also does not work.

If i am not mistaken, in Vue.js it is possible to render conditionally with **v-if** and i am searching for a possibility to make it in Nativescript-Vue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's the same like in Vue.js.

Instead of using `if` you should be using `v-if`.

[Playground example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=DnrOQ5)

Example:

```
<Label v-if="isRendering" text="This is a text"></Label>
```

But if you want to use an `if` in a `ListView` it's different.
Example:

```
<ListView for="item in listOfItems" @itemTap="onItemTap"> 
  <v-template>
    <Label :text="item.text" /> 
  </v-template>

  <v-template if="$odd">
    <!-- For items with an odd index, shows the label in red. -->
    <Label :text="item.text" color="red" />
  </v-template>
</ListView>
```

But more info about that in the [docs](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I already tried to use if like this:                    <StackLayout if="false" row="30"> ...
</StackLayout> but it doesn´t make anything, it always render the element. I dont want to use a ListView but i think i have to to use "if"

Comment: @Razzaui you should use `v-if` in your example instead of `if`. Check the Playground example. I made it for you so you can test it. Any more question just ask.